# StackOverflowError when using a query in a recursive method

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, recursion

In local database I have records with information about dirs and files (file system tree). For example, table "Dir" has attributes: **record_id** (autoincr.), **dir_id**, **dirname**, **parentDir_id**.
I need to create a files and dirs tree from database:

```
Dir_1
|
 -----Dir_1.1
 -----Dir_1.2
 -----File_1.1
Dir_2
|
 -----Dir_2.1
 -----Dir_2.2
 -----File_2.1
 -----File_2.2
Dir_3
File_1
File_2
```

So, I use recursive method.
My function:

```
 /**
 * Append new childs for target dir
 * @param targetObject directory
 */
public void addChilds(@Nullable SimpleSyncDirModel targetObject){
    //no target - main parent dir.
    if (targetObject == null){
        //get childs for this target object (main dir without parent)
        ArrayList<Object> foundedChilds = ThisApp.getDBhelper().getSharedSimpleObjects(this.dir_id);
        //step by step (childs). recursive mecthod.
        for (Object thisChild : foundedChilds){
            if (thisChild instanceof SimpleSyncDirModel){
                addNewChildDir((SimpleSyncDirModel) thisChild);
                //find and add childs for current child
                addChilds((SimpleSyncDirModel) thisChild);
            }else if (thisChild instanceof SimpleSyncFileModel){
                addNewChildFile((SimpleSyncFileModel) thisChild);
            }
        }
    }else{
        //get childs for this target object (not main, has parent)
        ArrayList<Object> foundedChilds = ThisApp.getDBhelper().getSharedSimpleObjects(targetObject.dir_id);
        //iterate, find and append childs (recursive)
        for (Object thisChild : foundedChilds){
            if (thisChild instanceof SimpleSyncDirModel){
                targetObject.addNewChildDir((SimpleSyncDirModel) thisChild);
                //recursive
                addChilds((SimpleSyncDirModel) thisChild);
            }else if (thisChild instanceof SimpleSyncFileModel){
                targetObject.addNewChildFile((SimpleSyncFileModel) thisChild);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As you see, I use function

> ThisApp.getDBhelper().getSharedSimpleObjects(targetObject.dir_id);

for searching childs of target dir. **targetObject.dir_id** - parent_id for "SELECT".

My search childs function:

```
 /**
 * Get childs with parent_id == 0 (without parent) or not (with parent)
 * @param parendDir_id ID of dir, for what we search childs
 * @return list of childs like {@link SimpleSyncDirModel}
 * and {@link ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncFileModel}
 */
public ArrayList<Object> getSharedSimpleObjects(String parendDir_id){

    ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

    //looking child dirs
    String[] columns_ = new String[]{
            "dir_id", "dirnameWithPath"
    };
    Cursor db_cursor = megashare_db.query(
            "SharedDir", columns_,
            "(parentDir_id = ?)",
            new String[] { parendDir_id },
            null, null, null);
    if (db_cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        db_cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (db_cursor.getPosition() != db_cursor.getCount()) {
            SimpleSyncDirModel simpleSyncDirModel = new SimpleSyncDirModel();
            simpleSyncDirModel.dir_id =
                    Integer.toString(db_cursor.getInt(db_cursor.getColumnIndex("dir_id")));
            simpleSyncDirModel.dirnameWithPath =
                    db_cursor.getString(db_cursor.getColumnIndex("dirnameWithPath"));
            result.add(simpleSyncDirModel);
            db_cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    db_cursor.close();

    //looking child files
    columns_ = new String[]{
            "file_id", "filenameWithPath"
    };
    db_cursor = megashare_db.query(
            "SharedFile", columns_,
            "(parentDir_id = ?)",
            new String[] { parendDir_id },
            null, null, null);
    if (db_cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        db_cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (db_cursor.getPosition() != db_cursor.getCount()) {
            SimpleSyncFileModel simpleSyncFileModel = new SimpleSyncFileModel();
            simpleSyncFileModel.file_id =
                    Integer.toString(db_cursor.getInt(db_cursor.getColumnIndex("file_id")));
            simpleSyncFileModel.filenameWithPath =
                    db_cursor.getString(db_cursor.getColumnIndex("filenameWithPath"));
            result.add(simpleSyncFileModel);
            db_cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    db_cursor.close();

    return result;
}
```

When I run my app and try to create file system tree, I always see **java.lang.StackOverflowError**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-23110
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
     at java.lang.ref.WeakReference.<init>(WeakReference.java:108)
     at java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry.<init>(WeakHashMap.java:71)
     at java.util.WeakHashMap.put(WeakHashMap.java:611)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.finishAcquireConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:980)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.tryAcquirePrimaryConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:916)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:682)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:400)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:905)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:586)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1283)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1154)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1322)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.managers.DBHelper.getSharedSimpleObjects(DBHelper.java:582)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:64)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
     at ru.rsit.megashare.models.global.SimpleSyncDirModel.addChilds(SimpleSyncDirModel.java:70)
    at
```

Error is here: `Cursor db_cursor = megashare_db.query`

Why I have this error? Of course I close always cursor. What I need to do for resolve this problem?

Comment: When developing recursice queries, always create a safety netting with a `LIMIT 100`, or whatever is the highest number of results you can imagine. That way  you still get valuable debugging info if you miss some special case in which the recursion ends up endless.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I understand. But I have two main dirs with childs that count not bigger than 80 items. Sorry for my English.

Comment: That is no guarantee that an amok recursion stays fewer than 200 or 200000 result rows.

Comment: I will try now to trace again this code. Maybe this recursion never ends. But I don't think so

Comment: I suggest you init the recursion by calling `addChilds(this)` and that `addChilds` doesn't do anything if the inparameter is `null`: `if (targetObject == null) { return; } else { .... your code ... }`. That way you avoid duplicate code and you also avoid a potential loop if `getSharedSimpleObjects` return s a list that contains `null`.

Comment: And also, replace `addChilds` with `addChildren`. And replace `foundedChilds` with `foundChildren`.

Comment: @Stefan, no, you are wrong. `if (targetObject == null)` then I understand, that current directory has now parent dir. So, I just search child dirs and after that in founded dirs I try to find childs, using `addChilds`. So, recursion runs in two ways: if current dir has parent, or not. I already find the reason of error in other code block

Answer (score 0):

The reason of error is mistake in code, where I try to find in database target dir for check: is this directory has no parent. So, my app duplicates some dirs, if I remove child object. That's why recursion going to cycle.